# Mobile NavBar issues

Tags: html, css

Thank you to everyone who have been helping me with my first project.

I have managed to make this responsive nav bar

1.However when the mobile menu is active the "burger" button is stuck to the left and small.

2. I have tried to make sub menus but had no success.

3.I have a logo i would like on the same line as the navigation menu but when the media is on a mobile devise (480px) I'm trying to have the logo on the top and center and the naviagtion on the line below.

any help will be great.  Thank you in advance.

this is the link to my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jkfb4Lus/

```
<body>

<div id="container">

    <header id="header">
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Writings">Writings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Extra">Extra</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="icon"><a id="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
</script>


</div>
</body>


body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    background-color:white;
}

/*remove margins and padding from the LIST, and add a black background color*/
ul.topnav{
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    float:right;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#333;
    text-align:right;
}

/*float the LIST (li) items side by side*/
ul.topnav li{
    display:inline;

}

/*float the LIST (li) items side by side HOVER*/
ul.topnav li:hover{
    border-bottom:;
}


/*style the (a)links inside the LI items*/
ul.topnav li a{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /* so it accepts top/bottom padding */
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:500;
    width:75px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:65px;
    width:100px;
}


/*change backround color of the LINKS (a) on hover*/
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color:#F1CBFF;
    color:purple;
    transition:background-color 1.0s ease;
}


/*hide the list (li) items that contains the link that 
should open and close-quotethe topnav on small screens*/
ul.topnav li.icon{
    display:none;
}


/*when the screen is less than 680px hide,hide all list (li)items,
except the first one("Home"). Show the list(li) item that contains
the link (a) open and close the topnav (li.icon)*/


@media screen and (max-width:680px){

#header{
    height:auto;
}

/*remove margins and padding from the LIST, and add a black background color*/
ul.topnav{
    height:auto;
}

ul.topnav li:not(:first-child){
        display:none;
        }

ul.topnav li.icon{
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
}

/*float the LIST (li) items side by side*/
ul.topnav li{
    float:left;
}
    }

/*the "responsive" class is added to the topnav with Javascript when the uses
clicks on the (icon).  This class makes the topnav look good on small screens*/
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position:relative;
    }

ul.topnav.responsive li.icon{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;

}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float:none;
    display:inline;

}

ul.topnav.responsive li a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover{
border-bottom:1px purple solid;
    transition:all 1.0s ease;   
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using flexbox?

```
ul.topnav.responsive li.icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: While flexbox is awesome, remember the comparability drawbacks http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox